# IndexOutOfBoundsException in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, indexoutofboundsexception

I recently received a crash report from one of my users on ASUS Transformer Pad TF700T running Android 4.1.1. I have seen similar crash reports for TextViews, typically replated to some custom code. This one is for WebView and there does not seem to be any code I wrote directly related to this crash.

I don't have more information, but this could happen when the user clicks on an edit box displayed inside a webview (I know the URL and content of the page that is shown in the webview). I don't have any idea how to approach this...

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (-4 ... -4) starts before 0
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1021)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:592)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setSelection(BaseInputConnection.java:497)
at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$WebViewInputConnection.setSelection(WebViewClassic.java:482)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:288)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:77)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, it appears a text selection with a negative start index is attempted to be made. At least, that's what the stracktrace tells you.:

Line 67 in `Selection`:

```
text.setSpan(SELECTION_START, start, start, Spanned.SPAN_POINT_POINT|Spanned.SPAN_INTERMEDIATE);
```

So apparently `start` has a value of `-4`. It gets passed in as a parameter and if you follow the trace back up, that value is parsed out of a `DO_SET_SELECTION` message.

I'm guessing that the error could occur if the text that's selected in the `WebView` changes while the selection is taking place, but without any extra details that's going to be difficult to confirm.

Interestingly, `BaseInputConnection.setSelection(int, int)` does contain an interesting code comment that makes my earier guess more plausible:

```
/**
 * The default implementation changes the selection position in the
 * current editable text.
 */
public boolean setSelection(int start, int end) {
    if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "setSelection " + start + ", " + end);
    final Editable content = getEditable();
    if (content == null) return false;
    int len = content.length();
    if (start > len || end > len) {
        // If the given selection is out of bounds, just ignore it.
        // Most likely the text was changed out from under the IME,
        // the the IME is going to have to update all of its state
        // anyway.
        return true;
    }
    if (start == end && MetaKeyKeyListener.getMetaState(content,
            MetaKeyKeyListener.META_SELECTING) != 0) {
        // If we are in selection mode, then we want to extend the
        // selection instead of replacing it.
        Selection.extendSelection(content, start);
    } else {
        Selection.setSelection(content, start, end);
    }
    return true;
}
```

There's an out of bounds check, but only on the upper bound, not the lower bound. Adding a check for `start < 0 || end < 0` would probably prevent the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as shown in your stracktrace from being thrown. Unfortunately that's probably not really going to help you, as it's unlikely you're going to be able to control the event flow from the `WebView`...

Comment: Nice analysis. Thanks! The question is: should I consider it a bug in WebView? Why would DO_SET_SELECTION contain negative start value even if the text changes?

Comment: The issue was fixed in Android 5.0. New condition is: `start > len || end > len || start < 0 || end < 0`